# Azure serverless functions without flask server in Python

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In AWS Lambda a serverless function is a small piece of code hosted somewhere. I can curl a url to run the code. In a python Function App v4, I seem to be forced to use a server. Is it possible to get a simple serverless function that just runs a piece of code like on AWS Lambda?

Removing the route annotations does not give a working function. Get a "no HTTP routes found" when I run the function locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an Azure Function Application uses a Flask server by default because [this tutorial would not exist then](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/flask-app-on-azure-functions/azure-functions-python-create-flask-app/). It is however definitely a server and you are forced to use it.

I do not get why it is the way it is, Microsoft is unique here. They call it a serverless function but in reality it is not. On AWS or GCP, if I want a second serverless function I would create another Lambda but on Azure have to edit the first function application and create another route. If I wanted routes and servers, I would just make one. It totally defeats the point of putting multiple small pieces of code in multiple functions and then exposing them through an API Gateway because there is one function application with all code running each time. In the end, we migrated out of Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create simple serverless functions that run a piece of code in response to events, including HTTP triggers.
Here is a small example-Python Azure Function with an HTTP trigger:

```html
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello, this is a serverless function!")
```

Open a terminal in the function app folder and give this command - func start

For no HTTP -

```html
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello, this is a serverless function!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

doublee-check that the function is properly set with the @func.HttpTrigger

```html
import azure.functions as func

@func.HttpTrigger(name='req', methods=['get', 'post'], auth_level='function')
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello, this is a serverless function!")
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I get `No HTTP routes mapped` and a url is not printed (if the function were correct, it would print a localhost url to call the function).

Comment: Extra logs for you: `Generating 0 job function(s). No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.). `

Comment: ihey buddy thanks for letting me know, can make sure that the function is correctly annotated with an HTTP trigger, ill extend how it should look with python in the answer section

Comment: and i take you have installed the needed packaged

Comment: If you are setting up a route annotation you get a server which OP does not want. OP says "I seem to be forced to use a server." and mentions AWS Lambda which is nothing like Function Application (or Cloud Functions for that matter).

Comment: for routing chck the answer i have updated it in the last part, lets see

Comment: and sorry aws lamda and azure func uses diff architecture and it is serverless but in background server still is running

Comment: Why do you need `auth_level=function`? I think anonymous is closer to what OP asks for.

Comment: "aws lamda and azure func uses diff architecture", do you have a good blog or essay explaining the details? Thanks!

Comment: Using the main method trick in No HTTP and setting AzureWebJobsStorage to UseDevelopmentStorage=true, I still get a `No HTTP routes mapped`.